# REACT JSX styles [object object]

Tags: reactjs

i'm studying about React but don't understand the JSX Styles.
here code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="disp"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var root = document.querySelector('#disp')
        const cssStyle = {
            'color': 'red',
            'backgroud-color': '#fff0f0',
            'font-size':'2em'
        }
        const scriptStyle = {
            color: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: '#fff0f0',
            fontSize: '2em'
        }
        function getDOM() {

            return (
                <div> 
                    <div style={scriptStyle}>
                        Look at the stars
                    </div>
                    <p stlye={cssStyle}>
                        Look how they shine for you
                    </p>
                </div>
            )
        }
        ReactDOM.render(getDOM(), root)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issue**

scriptStyle is good but I can not see cssStyle normally. [object object]
so how can I?

Comment: You have a typo, `stlye` instead of `style`. Also `backgroud-color` instead of `background-color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSX, styles are provided as an object, with keys being camelCase instead of snakeCase. For instance `background-color` will be written as `backgroundColor` which is exactly how it is being provided in `scriptStyle` object and that is how it needs to to given to the style. Apart from it you also have a typo in `style={cssStyle}`

Working demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="disp"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var root = document.querySelector('#disp')
        const cssStyle = {
            'color': 'red',
            'backgroudColor': '#fff0f0',
            'fontSize':'2em'
        }
        const scriptStyle = {
            color: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: '#fff0f0',
            fontSize: '2em'
        }
        function getDOM() {

            return (
                <div> 
                    <div style={scriptStyle}>
                        Look at the stars
                    </div>
                    <p style={cssStyle}>
                        Look how they shine for you
                    </p>
                </div>
            )
        }
        ReactDOM.render(getDOM(), root)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Docs Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)**

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
<p stlye={cssStyle}>
     Look how they shine for you
</p>
```

It should be `<p style=`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Atom code editor try writing out some conventional HTML styling like so:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label class="label" for="name">Enter name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" />
      <button style="background-color: blue; color: white;">Submit</button>
    </div>
  );

};
```

You will get a message saying that "Style prop must be an object" and you can read more about it here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/style-prop-object.md

So what does that all mean?

We have to change the syntax a bit. I am still going to say style equals, but after that, you need two curly braces one inside another.

The outer curly brace indicates we want to reference a javascript variable inside the jsx, the second set of curly braces within it, is meant to indicate a javascript object.

So when styling with jsx rather than providing a string like above, we instead provide a javascript object where all the keys to the object represent a different property we want to style. The values indicate the value for that particular styling.

Also, when providing a property name like background-color, you are going to remove the dash and capitalize the second word like so: backgroundColor. This is called camel case.

So in general, the conversion is straightforward, just remove the double quotes, replace them with curly braces and then if you have a compound property name, remove the dash and do a capitalization.
So with that in mind, I want you to give a shot to updating the style property here.

So the above code now looks like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label class="label" for="name">Enter name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" />
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: blue; color: white; }}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );

};
```